# Memory allocation inside already allocated memory in C

Tags: c

I have two structs

```
struct point {
     double x;
     double y;   
};

struct points_set {
      int num_of_points;
      struct point *points; //an array of points sets 
}
```

I need to implement memory allocation for **struct points_set**.
(i.e. to implement function `struct point_set *alloc_points(struct point p_arr[], int size);`)

As I see, we need to allocate memory twice, i.e. for point_set, and for the array of points that is inside the structure.

Firstly we allocate memory for the array that is supposed to be inside points_set, i.e.

```
struct point *arr_points = (struct point *)malloc(size * sizeof(point));
```

Then we allocate memory for the whole structure

```
struct point_set *setOfPoints = (struct point_set *)malloc(size * sizeof(struct points_set));
```

Finally, we make pointer from "setOfPoints" to "points"

```
setOfPoints->points = arr_points;
```

**Question:** Is it correct?

Comment: You don't need to cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: It may or may not be necessary to allocate `struct points_set` itself, it depends on your specific problem (and on the requirements of your assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: Is it correct?

Yes, but possibly you want:

```
struct point_set *setOfPoints = (struct point_set *)malloc(sizeof(struct points_set));
```

instead. In other words, do not multiply by `size` here, because you only want to allocate a single `struct point_set`, not many of them.

Comment: 1) Also assign `setOfPoints->num_of_points = size` 2) [Don't cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)